# WebAPI, muliple routes being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 routes as part of my webAPI, these accept the same parameters but have different static components to the route. Yet they both get called during requests.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("things/{id}/config/{optional?}")]
public dynamic ThingsConfig(int id, int optional = 0)
{
    // stuff happens
}
```

And

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("things/{id}/data/{optional?}")]
public dynamic ThingsData(int id, int optional = 0)
{
    // stuff happens
}
```

My route config in the Global.asax is unchanged from the out of the box version

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
```

If i comment out the [Route] lines then the API returns 404 errors as expected. However when they are present when one route is accessed then they both are eg:

```
http://localhost/api/things/1/config/
```

Will call both ThingsConfig and ThingsData

What have I done wrong here?

UPDATE:

I tried to simplify the problem.

Create a new VS 2015 solution.
File -> New -> Project

Check .NET Framework 4.5 is selected
Choose "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)" under C# -> Web

Select "web API"

"Change Authentication" to "No Authentication" (to simplify things a bit)

Made the following changes to the values controller:

Added the RoutePrefix to the controller itself - this seemed to be needed.
Added my two test routes - so the head of the controller now looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("things/{id}/config/{optional?}")]
    public dynamic ThingsConfig(int id, int optional = 0)
    {
        return "Config";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("things/{id}/data/{optional?}")]
    public dynamic ThingsData(int id, int optional = 0)
    {
        return "Data";
    }
```

No other changes were made to the default frame work.

Then called the two routes:

```
http://localhost:<port>/api/values/things/1/config
http://localhost:<port>/api/values/things/1/data
```

This works as I would have expected. You can call each route independently.

But my original solution still manages to call BOTH routes, can anyone suggest where I might have changed something that would allow this?

Comment: What is the difference between this and your original solution ? I think both are same only.

Comment: Not sure what the etiquette here is: the problem was not with the API it was with the client calling it. Both were actually being called. Should I just answer the question, or being as it was a non-issue just delete it? Don't want it to just vanish though as people have tried to help.

Comment: Bdw did you added "routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();" this line in your RouteConfig, before your routes.MapRoute(...) method ?? Plz add this and check once and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was with the client - it was actually calling both routes. Testing the raw API with Fiddler did not display the issue.

File this one under "problem between keyboard and chair".

Answer (score 1):

Think, you have created api controller and looking at controller routes registration.

So you need to follow below steps to refer webapi in your project.

But your implementation will give error because of duplication .

Multiple actions were found that match the request: ThingsConfig on type FailTracker.Controllers.ThingsController ThingsData on type FailTracker.Controllers.ThingsController